# Awesomium incorrectly prints pages to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, awesomium

Why Awesomium incorectly prints web sites to PDF? This is my code:

```
   private void _browser_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        _Status.Content = "Printing to pdf...";
        WebControl tempControl = sender as WebControl;
        tempControl.WebSession.Views.First().PrintToFile("E:\\", PrintConfig.Default);
        _Status.Content = "Done.";
    }
```

Result of following code is under that link (http://google.pl):
[Link to dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsxjmavx48lkvwc/Zrzut%20ekranu%202014-07-31%2014.03.31.png)

As You can see a lot of elements looks like are partially loaded. How to resolve this? Is someone experiencing similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the frame that has just been loaded is actually the page, and not any other thing.

**To do that, make an `If` check for [`e.IsMainFrame=true`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_FrameEventArgs_IsMainFrame), then you can happily print.**

*Beware that some pages could load things via AJAX, so if you rely on the `LoadingFrameComplete` event you could get spinning wheels instead of content.*